Unable to embed external SQL scripts into Azure bicep deployment scripts
We have a SQL script that gets published to Azure artifacts. Then a deployment script using bicep to deploy the sql script to the database.
It picks up the file but throws the following error.
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 22:53:14 - The deployment 'testSqlDeploymentScript' failed with error(s). Showing 1 out of 1 error(s).
Status Message: The provided script failed with the following error:
System.Management.Automation.ParseException: At line:2 char:17
+ IF OBJECT_ID(N'[testTable]') IS NULL
+                 ~
Array index expression is missing or not valid.
at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create(Parser parser, String fileName, String fileContents)
at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create(ExecutionContext context, String script)
at System.Management.Automation.CommandInvocationIntrinsics.NewScriptBlock(String scriptText)
at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand.ProcessRecord()
at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoProcessRecord()
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
at , /mnt/azscripts/azscriptinput/DeploymentScript.ps1: line 310. Please refer to https://aka.ms/DeploymentScriptsTroubleshoot for more deployment
script information. (Code:DeploymentScriptError)
I am aware of the ADO yaml taks such as SqlAzureDacpacDeployment but I need to do deploy the sql script (sqlScript.sql) with bicep deployment.
We have tried writing the string to the file and invoking with SQL command but no luck.
This is the bicep file.
 param location string = resourceGroup().location 
 @secure() 
 param sharedAccessToken string = '' 
 param addSqlFile string = loadTextContent('../sqlScript.sql')


 resource deploySqlScript
 'Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts@2023-08-01' = {   name:
 'deploy-sql-script'   location: location   kind: 'AzurePowerShell'  
 properties: {
     azPowerShellVersion: '9.7'
     timeout: 'PT5M'
     retentionInterval: 'PT1H'
     supportingScriptUris: []
     arguments: '-accessToken ${sharedAccessToken}  -sqlScriptFile ${addSqlFile}'
     scriptContent: '''
         Param (
           [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $accessToken,
           [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $sqlScriptFile
         )
         
         Install-Module sqlserver -AllowClobber -Force -Scope CurrentUser
         Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $serverInstance -Database $databaseName -AccessToken "$accessToken" -InputFile $sqlScriptFile
 
     '''   } }

This is an example of the sql script (sqlScript.sql).
'
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[testTable]') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE '[testTable]' (
        [testId] nvarchar(150) NOT NULL,
        [testVersion] nvarchar(32) NOT NULL
    );
END;
GO
'

Any suggestion on how to embed the scripts to Azure SQL database using bicep?

The error looks like an issue with the driver used to make the SQL connection between client and server that is built into PS.  It may have to do with versions of the driver.  You are using azPowerShellVersion: '9.7'.  I would use SQL Server Management Studio to login to server.  Than check the log files in the explorer under Management to see more detail error.  The should be a login to the server for each connection made to server that contains the Group and User.  I'm suspecting that it is a PS bug.

Does it work if you manually run the deployment related commands with the same Dacpac file and bicep files from your local develop machine? If it also not work on your machine, the problem should on the configurations in your bicep files or the database project itself. @albbla91

Hi @BrightRan-MSFT, yes it works when I run the Invoke command with the same file on my local sql server instance.
It also works if I use Invoke command to run a query instead of the file using bicep deployment script. For e.g. (Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $serverInstance -Database $databaseName -AccessToken "$accessToken" -Query 'SELECT * FROM sys.Tables')
Not sure why it wouldn't work using bicep.

@albbla91, What commands and tasks are you using in the pipeline run the bicep deployment? Do you run the exactly same commands with exactly same input parameters as that you run on your local machine?

@BrightRan-MSFT I am running the following command locally in Powershell and along with a task in ADO to test.
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name "testSqlDeploymentScript" -ResourceGroupName "" -TemplateFile "" TemplateParameterFile ""
ADO task - AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
Btw, I have updated the question with sqlscript file and the error.

@albbla91, Try to use the AzurePowerShell@5 task in pipeline to run the same Azure PowerShell command lines as that you run on local machine.

@albbla91, And post the detailed YAML content of your pipeline to your above question.
